# Ubuntu Firewall UFW

Tags: ufw

I want to make a rule on my UFW, that make it comunicate with only the ip ranges that i will update there to only one port, and not accept any else on that port. Can sb help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use subnet masks in ufw to specify the ip ranges as shown in the example below:

```
sudo ufw allow from 15.15.15.0/24  to any port 22
```

In this example, the IP range is from 15.15.15.1 to 15.15.15.255 and the one port is 22.

See [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) and [UFW Essentials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands) for more.

Hope this helps